# Angular 5 http post/put update ui

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-http

I can't get my UI to update after an http post/put call in angular 5.
The variable `this.showSuccesMessage` is always false.

```
const sequence$ = this.http.post("http://localhost:5000/api/testcall",
  obj, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
  responseType: 'text' });

  sequence$.subscribe(() => {console.log('ok done');
  this.showSuccesMessage = true;
});
```

I even tried the NgZone methoth (zone.run). who can help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: does the request fire at all (see developer tools -> network)? does the console.log happen?

Comment: Can you check in the Network tab of the dev console what is the raw response you get? Maybe it is not a success response.

Comment: Please, provide more information. We need to know if the `console.log` statement has been execute or if the http call has failed (in your developper tool) . Also how did you check the value of showSuccessMessage. If it's because a message isn't displayed that you consider your variable to be falsy, then provide your template as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The call executed correctly and I can see the the console.log message in my developer console tool but the variable showmessage is still false. Do I need to add an async pype ?

Comment: I bet this is a typo and you put an extra "s" in it somewhere else (since "success" is normally spelled with to ss)

Comment: Do you have `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` anywhere in your component chain?